# What is the difference between CREATE INDEX and ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have searched the web but I have failed to find a conclusive answer for this question.

Is there any difference between `CREATE INDEX` and `ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX`?

Are there any problems that may arise when I use one or the other or do both work the same way?

Server version: 5.5.32 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Answer (score 5):

The  [`CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html) syntax requires an index name, whereas the [`ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) syntax doesn't.

This question as already been [asked and answered](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46623/create-index-vs-alter-table-add-index-mysqlism-or-sql-standard) and should be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I have created an event, but when the execution time reaches, the column in the database is not update. What causes this?